# Unable to move to a previous point in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Let's assume that I am at manual A. I press

```
enter
```

and I am now at manual B.

**How can you return to the previous manual** by one command in Emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try typing "`C-h m`" to get a mode list in the help window, there you'll find

```
...
C-c C-b     help-go-back
...
```

which seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

The subject is a bit misleading. You don't really want to return to the previous point but view the previously browsed manual.

But while editing, if you jump across the buffer and then want to move the point to the previous place, you can type <kbd>C-x C-@</kbd> which runs `pop-global-mark`.